# Не работает проверка логина! Использовала метод $.ajax(), чтобы проверка выполнялась на стороне пользователя. Подскажите, где ошибка?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form

При смене фокуса с поля ввода данных должна выполняться проверка введённых данных и появляться предупреждение о некорректности рядом с полем. При неправильно введённом логине ничего не происходит, и данные спокойно отправляются в базу данных. Регулярные выражения написаны корректно.

***registration.php***

```
<div name="blockForm" class="form" id="reg">
            <form name="regForm" action="registrationCheck.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="login" class="reg_form" id="login" onblur="responseLog();" placeholder="Логин" required /><br />
                    <span id="errorLog" style="display: none">Логин введён некорректно! Логин должен начинаться со строчной или прописной буквы, он может содержать цифры или символы (._-\)</span>
                <input type="submit" name="save" class="reg_form" id="save_reg" onclick="resetRegForm()" value="Сохранить" />
            </form>
</div>
```

***registration.js***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function responseLog() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkRegLog.php",
            data: { action: 'login', user: $("#login").val() },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'true') {
                    $("#errorLog").css("display", "block");
                    $("#errorLog").css("color", "red");
                } else {
                    $("#login").css("background", "green");
                };
            }
        });
    };
    function resetRegForm() {
        $("#errorLog").css("display", "none");
    };
});
```

***checkReg.php***

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $mysql = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "yoursmilebase");
    if ($action == "login") {
            $row = $mysql->query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$action'");
            if ($row) {
                echo "true";
            } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d._-\\]{5,15}/", $action) || preg_match("/^(admin)/", $action)) {
                echo "true";
            } else {
                echo "false";
            };
     }
    $mysql->close;
?>
```

Comment: Прочитай пожалуйста [ask] и [mcve], разбираться в этом полотне кода никто здесь не будет.

Comment: Просто 1 взгляд.. `global $action = $_POST['action'];` - и дальше этот же action вы юзаете в запросе. В чём смысл и зачем тогда ещё user передаёте? - есть 99% уверенностью что ошибка именно тут.

Comment: `$mysql->query` вернет falsy-значение только в случае ошибки. Отсутствие нужной записи ошибкой __не является__. `var_dump($row)` прекрасно бы все пояснил.